# How can I refresh an element on a page after the user clicks a download link?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is part of my view, which can easily be put in a partial if necessary.

```
<% if order_item.still_downloadable == true %>
  <%= "Photo ##{order_item.gallery_photo.id} - " %>
  <%= link_to "Download here", download_order_order_item_path(@order, order_item) %>
  &bull; You may download this <%= pluralize(5 - order_item.download_count, 'more time') %>.
<% else %>
  <%= "Photo ##{order_item.gallery_photo.id} - #{order_item.title}" %>
  &bull; You may not download this file any more.
<% end %>
```

Here is the download action in the order_items controller.

```
def download
  @order_item = OrderItem.find(params[:id])
  @gallery_photo = GalleryPhoto.find(@order_item.gallery_photo_id)
  @order_item.update_attribute(:download_count, @order_item.download_count += 1)
  send_file @gallery_photo.image.path(:original), :x_sendfile => true, :type => 'image/jpg'
end
```

What is the best way to refresh that part of the view (or even the whole page) so the download count is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a download action and forced the show page to not cache, so when the users goes back to the show page the browser is forced to reload it. In the show action:

```
response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but you can do this:

```
$('.download').click(function(){
  setTimeout("window.location.reload()",1000);//or other value
})
```

Or I would encourage you to create a function that will sends xhr request after someone cliked download, and update element with download count.

Comment: I hesitated on this idea because there's always that possibility that the request for the download action takes longer than 1000ms to process.